# Reek codesmell Duplicate Method call fix

Tags: ruby, reek

I'm getting below errors from `reek`:

```
lib/actions.rb -- 5 warnings:
  Actions#move_forward calls (self.x_coordinate + unit) twice (DuplicateMethodCall)
  Actions#move_forward calls place((self.x_coordinate + unit), self.y_coordinate, self.direction) twice (DuplicateMethodCall)
  Actions#move_forward calls self.direction 5 times (DuplicateMethodCall)
  Actions#move_forward calls self.x_coordinate 4 times (DuplicateMethodCall)
  Actions#move_forward calls self.y_coordinate 4 times (DuplicateMethodCall)
```

Below is the method move_forward

```
def move_forward(unit = 1)
        case self.direction
        when Direction::SOUTH
            place(self.x_coordinate, self.y_coordinate - unit, self.direction)
        when Direction::EAST
            place(self.x_coordinate + unit, self.y_coordinate, self.direction)
        when Direction::NORTH
            place(self.x_coordinate, self.y_coordinate + unit, self.direction)
        when Direction::WEST
            place(self.x_coordinate - unit, self.y_coordinate, self.direction)
        else

        end
    end
```

I want to remove all errors especially duplicate method call. What would be the best way to fix all warnings in this case?

Comment: Your east and west directions do indeed have identical code, and that is probably a bug. The `reek` output doesn't appear to match your code sample - you *have* used unit, and the output you pasted refers to calls including `self.x_coordinate + 1`. Could you please check this and ensure the two things match (it makes it harder to understand and suggest improvements if they do not).

Comment: Sorry just updated Reek error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def move_forward(unit = 1)
  x, y, d = x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction
  case d
  when Direction::SOUTH
    place(x, y - unit, d)
  when Direction::EAST, Direction::WEST
    place(x + unit, y, d)
  when Direction::NORTH
    place(x, y + unit, d)
  else
  end
end
```

I find the complaints about the "duplicate calls" to `self.x_coordindate` and `self.y_coordinate` kinda false-positivey though, they're only called once per path.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I think it's a bit ridiculous but just went ahead with the changes and as expected now with no errors.

Comment: `reek` seems to like DRY code. Partly because it is easy to detect repeats. However, it isn't as ridiculous as it seems - it's not a "false positive" based on number of times called, but a reference to how often you type the same thing into your methods. In turn this is a measure of how much effort it would take you to fix that code if for instance you needed to change how any of the methods in it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The code "smell" that is triggering the `reek` reports is that you are calling to a method that sets state of several instance variables, when a lot less is changing in practice (for instance direction doesn't change at all). The `place` method sets everything, which makes using it to make a small change overly verbose.

This would probably factor the method down to cause less reported problems:

```
def move_forward(unit = 1)
  case direction
  when Direction::SOUTH
    move_relative( 0, -unit )
  when Direction::EAST
    move_relative( unit, 0 )
  when Direction::WEST
    move_relative( -unit, 0 )
  when Direction::NORTH
    move_relative( 0, unit )
  end
end

def move_relative( delta_x, delta_y )
  place( x_coordinate + delta_x, y_coordinate + delta_y, direction )
end
```

(Also I couldn't resist "fixing" your WEST movement, sorry if that's actually wrong)

Comment: You are right. I actually kind of knew that was the case but just wanted to check whether this was the best way... Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be using the power of object orientation

What about a solution that instead uses the power of your pre-existing objects?

```
def move_forward(by_how_much = 1) 
  move_relative(*direction.change_in_coords(by_how_much))
end

def move_relative(delta_x, delta_y)
  place( x_coordinate + delta_x, y_coordinate + delta_y, direction )
end

class Direction::SOUTH
  def self.change_in_coords(unit = 1)
    [0, -unit]
  end
end
```